# Explicit iteration counter privatisation with OMP parallel for

Tags: c, gcc, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a few questions about parallelisation using OMP.

Say I have a program, within which there is a nested for loop. From my understanding of the directive `#pragma omp parallel for`, the outer iteration counter is automatically privatised. Is the same true for the inner iteration counter? This *appears* to be the case, as the outputs are identical whether I state it explicitly or not.

**Is it necessary(/safer) to explicitly privatise iteration counters for `for` loops within a parallel for block?**

I am compiling with GCC - I found that I had some unhelpful crosstalk between threads when using GCC 5.4.0, but not when using GCC 7.5.0. To resolve this, I added `private(foo, bar)` to the directive, but I am curious as to why it works without this statement for GCC 7.5.0. **Does the GCC (7.5.0) automatically identify race conditions/crosstalk and privatise things it thinks should be private?**

Other than allocating a few additional memory addresses, **is there any significant overhead cost in privatising variables?** I think likely 'yes, but (in my case) negligible'. Target audience for code will be using systems with ~10s-100s of cores

Toy example, which finds maximum values in chunks along an array:

```c
find_max(double *inArr, double *outArr, int64_t nSamps, int64_t nCells, int64_t threads) {
    double  maxVal, curVal;
    int64_t t, cell;

    #pragma omp parallel for private(maxVal, curVal) num_threads(threads)
    for (t=0; t<nSamps; t++) {
        maxVal = inArr[t];
        for (cell=1; cell<nCells; cell++) {
            curVal = inArr[cell * nSamps + t];
            if (curVal > maxVal) {
                maxVal = curVal;
            }
        }
        outArr[t] = maxVal;
    }
}
```

I am building this as an extension module for a Python library - the call to gcc is:

```
gcc -pthread -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -c src.c -o src.o -fopenmp -fPIC -Ofast
```

Comment: There should be no change between compiler versions and the variables should be shared. The compiler however might eliminate their use or do whatever so that might make it look like it works. Declaring them private will put them in a separate per thread stack and it doesn’t really cause performance issues.

Comment: Yep, hadn't considered elimination, thanks.

I understand there shouldn't be a change between version, but there is - it occurs when I introduce a variable to track the sum of values in each chunk and then use that find a normalised value (returned in an additional array). With GCC 7.5.0, the result is exactly as expected, but with GCC 5.4.0 there's obvious bleed between the threads. Should I edit the toy example to illustrate?

Comment: Write modern code! You should declare the variables in their minimum scope, then you won't have to privatize them.

Comment: `cell` should be private. OpenMP makes automatically private only loop variables of the loops associated with the `for` construct.